# PLS-00201: el identificador 'UTL_FILE' se debe declarar

Tags: sql, oracle

intento leer archivos desde oracle-xe-18c pero me sale este error con solamente abrir el archivo:

```
Error que empieza en la línea: 1 del comando :

Informe de error -
ORA-06550: línea 3, columna 10:
PLS-00201: el identificador 'UTL_FILE' se debe declarar
ORA-06550: línea 3, columna 10:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: línea 7, columna 5:
PLS-00320: la declaración de tipo de esta expresión está incompleta o tiene un formato incorrecto
ORA-06550: línea 7, columna 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: línea 9, columna 21:
PLS-00320: la declaración de tipo de esta expresión está incompleta o tiene un formato incorrecto
ORA-06550: línea 9, columna 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

ya había creado el directorio de archivos desde el usuario sys de esta forma:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY archivos_csv  AS '/home/seed/Documentos/fundamentos_db/proyecto/electoral_web/electoral_web/electoral_web/static/datos_generados_csv';
```

y di permisos a mi usuario con el que estoy trabajando de esta forma:

```
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY archivos_csv TO admpuno;
```

estoy intentando abrir el archivo de esta forma sencilla:

```
declare

funo utl_file.file_type;

begin

funo := utl_file.fopen('archivos_csv', 'neighborhoods_data.csv', 'r');

utl_file.fclose(funo);

end;/
```

no se que estoy haciendo mal!!!

Answer (score 1):

era muy sencilla la solución
solo es ejecutar lo siguiente

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY archivos_dir
AS  'direccion_de_tu_directorio/directorio'

GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_FILE TO PUBLIC;
grant all on directory archivos_dir to tuUsuario;  

commit;
```